# Ajax request Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, view

I currently have a variable that I need to pass from a view to a controller and then to a different view.
The data is being sent successfully but I'm not sure what to do with it in the controller. Ideally what I'd like to do is take the variable I have passed to the controller, and then pass that to another view and display it.

My view at the moment:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var svg = chart1.getSVG()
        .replace(/</g, '\n&lt;') 
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_controller/accept",
        data: svg,
        success: function(data){
            alert('Successful!');
            console.log(svg);
        }
    });
});
```

The data is being logged in the console but nothings happening in the controller (I'm not sure what to do with the data).

What I've tried in the controller is:

```
if($_POST):
    print_r("success");
    return true;
endif;
```

But I can't even seem to print it to actually do anything with it, can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: in ajax url  use url: <?php echo base_url(); ?>"index.php/admin_controller/accept",

Comment: Thats what I'm using at the moment, I just don't know what to do with the variable once I receive it @AslamPatel

Comment: now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

change in your ajax url

```
url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_controller/accept"
```

to

```
url:<?php echo base_url(); ?>"index.php/admin_controller/accept"
```

Comment: Or even better, always post it as function argument. I.e. `<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin_controller/accept'); ?>`.

Comment: Oh no its posting to the controller fine, I just don't know what to do with it in the controller, I can see the variable being logged in the console and everything